# SQL: Creating new columns using Case When, Grouping_ID

Tags: mysql

How do I create an entirely new column in SQL while using `CASE WHEN`, `GROUPING_ID()`, and `ROLLUP()` syntax?

So far I have tried:

```
SELECT Country, ContactTitle, COUNT(ContactTitle) AS Count
,CASE(
WHEN
GROUPING_ID(Legend) = 0 THEN ' '
WHEN
GROUPING_ID(Legend) = 1 THEN 'SUBTOTAL(Country)')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Country, ContactTitle)
FROM dbo.Customers
```

Comment: mysql  or oracle ???

Comment: `dbo`? Smells like MS Sql Server? Not MySql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Country, ContactTitle, COUNT(ContactTitle) AS Count, 
CASE 
    WHEN GROUPING_ID(Country,ContactTitle) = 0 THEN ''
    WHEN GROUPING_ID(Country,ContactTitle) = 1 THEN CONCAT('Subtotal for ',Country)
END AS Legend
FROM dbo.Customers
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Country, ContactTitle);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` needs an `END`.

And while testing, you could output the GROUPING_ID or GROUPING to understand what they return.

```
SELECT Country, ContactTitle, COUNT(*) AS Count,
 (CASE
  WHEN GROUPING_ID(Country, ContactTitle) = 1
  THEN CONCAT('SUBTOTAL(',Country,')')
  WHEN GROUPING(Country) = 1
  THEN 'TOTAL'
  ELSE ' '
  END) AS Legend
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country, ContactTitle WITH ROLLUP;
```